# CoffeScript not working in Rails Production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails website that works excellent in development and in test.  However, in the production environment I am having issues with CoffeeScript.  The following JQuery tab function is not running in production:

```
jQuery ->
  $("#tabs").tabs()
```

The above runs correctly in dev and test.  It is located in the corresponding CoffeeScript file for the controller in the asset pipeline (assets/javascripts/insight.js.coffee).  I have tried cleaning and then compiling my assets with:

```
rake assets:clean
rake assets:precompile
```

Here is my config file for production:

```
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Compile all files in assets folders
  files = Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', '{javascripts,stylesheets}', '**', '[^_]*.{js,css}*')]
  files.map! {|file| file.sub(%r(#{Rails.root}/app/assets/(javascripts|stylesheets)/), '') }
  files.map! {|file| file.sub(%r(\.(coffee|scss)), '') }
  config.assets.precompile += files

  config.assets.digest = true
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Rails but :

assets/javascripts/insight.js.coffee

It seems that you miss a point (".") in this part of your regexp  `{js,css}*`

```
 # Compile all files in assets folders
  files = Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', '{javascripts,stylesheets}', '**', '[^_]*.{js,css}.*')]
```